# How does Vaishnava theology reconcile Brahman having no anger but experiencing anger?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, brahman

How does Vaishnava theology reconcile Brahman having no anger but experiencing anger?

For example, the Vishnu Purana says:

> He is all, he knows all, he sees all, he possess all strength, all knowledge, all power, all wealth. He is without fatigue, without lassitude, without fear, **without anger**, without desire and other such blemishes.

The Bhagavad Gita even says it's an asuric quality:

> Religious hypocrisy, hubris, self-conceit, anger, rudeness and ignorance these, O Arjuna,
>   belong to asuric beings.

But we know well the Narasimha avatar where Brahman gets really angry at the injustice towards his devotees (Prahlada).

Vedanta Desikan in the *Nyaya Siddhanjana* says:

> Karma is nothing but the affection and anger
>   of God

He even says this is a good quality:

> Conditioned with various karma of the Jivatmas, the knowledge of God forms anger and love. But it is not a defect for him because His anger is a good quality consistent with keeping His own command.

How to reconcile?

Comment: Even when He is angry, His anger is under His control. He does not indulge in mindless destruction out of anger. He gets angry to punish evil-doers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bhagavad Gita 4.9](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/4/verse/9)

> जन्म कर्म च मे दिव्यमेवं यो वेत्ति तत्त्वत:
>   त्यक्त्वा देहं पुनर्जन्म नैति मामेति सोऽर्जुन
>
> janma karma cha me divyam evaṁ yo vetti tattvataḥ
>   tyaktvā dehaṁ punar janma naiti mām eti so Arjuna

*"My Birth and Actions are Divine"*

Above answers your recent questions about how to reconcile:

1. Brahman having no desire/anger but desiring to create?
2. Brahman having infinite bliss but experiencing sorrow?
3. Brahman having no births but taking multiple avataras?

The entire point of Brahmam 'doing' anything in Leela Vibhuthi (universe as we know it) is to show Baddha-Atmas (jivatmas that have not attained Moksha yet), that He is different from us, and that He is doing it for us.

His desires and our desires are not the same.
His is 100% unselfish. Ours is 99% selfish.

Brahman has no desire/anger/birth - because the very word 'desire/anger/birth' brings up certain meanings in your head - and Brahmam has none of those.

He takes birth so we can avoid it.
He shows anger so we can be protected.
He shows sorrow so that we think of him as one of us and accept his advice.

That is why Vaishnava theology says 'There is none Like him'. There is absolutely no simile in the world to describe him. If there was, what would be the difference between Him and us ?

That is why Vedas say he is 'Aprameya' - He cannot be known.
Does that mean he is like a flying teapot around earth - which also cannot be known ?

The difference is that it IS possible to know whether there is a flying teapot around earth by systematically scanning every point in space.

But there is no such way known to man or deva or rishi or Shiva or Brahma, about how to know Brahmam.